# How to get Expression<Func<object>> target object to set value?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, func

I try to create a function to compare original and updated value and set original to the updated if different. The function do much more so I simplified to focus on the subject:

```
public void Match<T>(Expression<Func<object>> original, Expression<Func<object>> updated)
{
    var mex = original.Body as MemberExpression;

    var funcOriginal = original.Compile();
    var funcUpdated = updated.Compile();

    var valueOriginal = funcOriginal();
    var valueUpdated = funcUpdated();

    if (valueOriginal != valueUpdated)
    {
       var info = mex.Member as PropertyInfo;
       var target = ???; //How to get the original.TestProperty here?

       info.SetValue(target, valueUpdated);
    }
}
```

I would like to call like this:

```
manager.Match<TestClass>(() => original.TestProperty, () => updated.TestProperty);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Expression` property of your member info is a representation of the variable the property is being fetched from.  You simply need to invoke that to evaluate it to a value.

```
public static void Match<T>(Expression<Func<T>> original, 
    Expression<Func<T>> updated)
{
    var mex = original.Body as MemberExpression;
    var valueOriginal = original.Compile()();
    var valueUpdated = updated.Compile()();

    if (!object.Equals(valueOriginal, valueUpdated))
    {
        var info = mex.Member as PropertyInfo;

        var target = Expression.Lambda(mex.Expression).Compile().DynamicInvoke();

        info.SetValue(target, valueUpdated);
    }
}
```

Of course, if this type is a value type then what you'll be creating by invoking this expression is a copy of that value, and you'll end up mutating the copy, but so long as it's a reference type you'll be copying the reference, and the actual object will in fact be mutated.

There is another quite different avenue that you can take though.  Rather than trying to evaluate the variable that you can assign this property to, you can simply create an expression that represents assigning the value that you have to that expression.  This code will even work if the property is accessed from a value type, because it's actually mutating the *variable* rather than getting the value of that variable and mutating it.

```
public static void Match<T>(Expression<Func<T>> original, 
    Expression<Func<T>> updated)
{
    var mex = original.Body as MemberExpression;
    var valueOriginal = original.Compile()();
    var valueUpdated = updated.Compile()();

    if (!object.Equals(valueOriginal, valueUpdated))
    {
        var body = Expression.Assign(
            Expression.MakeMemberAccess(mex.Expression, mex.Member),
            updated.Body);

        Expression.Lambda<Action>(body).Compile().Invoke();
    }
}
```

You also didn't actually use your generic argument for the type of the result of your two functions, despite making the method generic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want type safety you can pass in original

```
public void Match<TSource, TType>(TSource dest, Expression<Func<TSource, TType>> original, TType updateValue)
{
    var originalValue = original.Compile()(dest);
    if (!updateValue.Equals(originalValue))
    {
        // get prop name from expression
        var prop = original.GetMemberInfo().Name;
        typeof(TSource).GetProperty(prop).SetValue(dest, updateValue);
    }
}

//helper class to get propinfo from expression
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static MemberInfo GetMemberInfo(this Expression expression)
    {
        var lambda = (LambdaExpression) expression;

        MemberExpression memberExpression;
        if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression)
        {
            var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression) lambda.Body;
            memberExpression = (MemberExpression) unaryExpression.Operand;
        }
        else
            memberExpression = (MemberExpression) lambda.Body;

        return memberExpression.Member;
    }
}
```

use it like

```
manager.Match(original, o=>o.TestProperty, updated.TestProperty);
```

I didn't test it but should work or get you close.